# JSP compilation Error with Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am getting below error in my application.Login Page is not coming up.
I also confirmed that drools-core-5.4.0.Final.jar file is not corrupted and it is coming for all jar in classpath.

Earlier it was working and now suddenly it stopped working.

Any help or clue will be very helpful.

Regards
Anju Singh

`Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
error: error reading D:\Program Files\pw\apps3rdparty\drools\drools-core-5.4.0.Final.jar; cannot read zip file
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
Note: D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
Note: D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
1 warning
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:263)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)`

---

### New Stacktrace

`An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
1 warning
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:263)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at com.proactivenet.servlet.SSOTokenFilter.doFilter(SSOTokenFilter.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at com.bmc.atrium.sso.agents.web.SSOFilter.doFilter(SSOFilter.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
DEBUG 01/04 16:41:10 org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil An exception occurs when running the PrivilegedExceptionAction block.
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
error: error reading D:\Program Files\BMC Software\ProactiveNet\pw\apps3rdparty\drools\drools-core-5.4.0.Final.jar; cannot read zip file
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java]
Note: D:\Program Files\pw\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\jsp\Login_jsp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.`

Comment: Corrupted ZIP file? Have you enabled `antiResourceLocking`?

Comment: Zip file is not corrupted and i have not enabled antiResourceLocking.

Comment: Is there any more to the stack trace? How about in the `catalina.out` log file?

Comment: in logs only catalina.log file is present, can u tell me how to get catalina.out file?

Comment: I am sending u stacktrace:

Comment: new stacktrace is appended below of main content

Comment: It's pretty clear that the Drools JAR library isn't readable, either due to file permissions or file corruption. Double-check `D:\Program Files\BMC Software\ProactiveNet\pw\apps3rdparty\drools\drools-core-5.4.0.Final.jar` with the `jar` utility to ensure it is readable.

Comment: I have cross verified and jar is having enough permission and it is not corrupted. When I comment this jar in my conf file classpath variable them same error comes for next jar file.

Comment: Perhaps your permissions-check isn't correct. What is the effective user of the Tomcat process?

Comment: My fault, Issue was with jars only, Thanks for your all help :)